# What are the connections between spectral expansion and differential operator?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, spectral-theory

For instance, for a nice function $f$ on the unit circle, we have its Fourier expansion, 
$$f(x)=\sum_n \hat{f}(n) e^{inx},$$
where the exponentials are eigenfunctions for differential operator $d/dx.$

I feel confunsed about the connection between the differential operator and spectral expansion of an arbitrary function. (In the example above, the connection between $d/dx$ and the Fourier expansion.) Why do people often say a differential operator (e.g., Laplacian) has a spectral expansion?

Thank you!

Comment: Differential operators are a linear operator on a vector space.  Linear operators/maps have eigenvectors.  When functions are written in this basis, differentiating becomes really easy because each term is just an eigenvector.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you so much for this question, the above realisation only just really hit me.  $e^{2\pi i n x}$ are the orthogonal  eigenvectors of a hermitian operator $-i \frac{d}{dx}$ acting on $S^1$ functions.  I have so many things to think about now!

Comment: @muzzlator Thanks for the comments! Yes, I know the spectral expansion facilitates solving differential equation, but is it the only motivation? (Just kidding: I myself find it easier to differentiate $x$ than to first write its Fourier expansion and then differentiate the expansion...)

Comment: That seems good enough for me.  I just started reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics after this post and it's very interesting.  Those electron configuration pictures I remember seeing back in school are all just eigenfunctions on a sphere but for a different harmonic operator.